# Generic class or generic method? Which is a good practice?

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I have 3 different classes:

```
class A
{
  public int property1;
  public int property2;
  // so on..
}

class B
{
  public int property11;
  public int property22;
  //so on.
}

class Consumer
{
  public int property111;
  public int property222;
  //so on.
}

// Business logic in other class
if (someCondition)
{
    var serviceCall1 = GetValuesForClassA();
    A obj = serviceCall.Response;
}

else if (someOtherCondition)
{
    var serviceCall2 = GetValuesForClassB();
    B obj = serviceCall2.Response;
}
```

After I get the values of particular type I am assigning it to the properties of Consumer type via a generic function as below:

```
private void ApplyProperties<T>(T serviceResponse, Consumer obj)
 where T: class
{
    if (serviceResponse.GetType().Name == "A") // where A = class name
    {
        A newObj = (A)(object)serviceResponse;

        //Assign properties of Consumer obj here.
    }
    else if(serviceResponse.GetType().Name == "B") // where B = class name
    {
        B newObj = (B)(object)serviceResponse;

        //Assign properties of Consumer obj here.
    }
}
```

I have followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39244449/cast-generic-type-parameter-to-a-specific-type-in-c-sharp) example. I was unclear on how to change my code in a more cleaner way, hence the question.

Comment: If your code enters different code paths based on the type of its type arguments, arguably it isn't generic. In the sense that "generic" means "applies to multiple things". Which your code doesn't, as it only applies to one type at a time. You probably don't need generics here, nor all the casting magic. You may be better off using AutoMapper, especially if readable code is your end goal.

Comment: Having a type checking inside a generic method means that you have something incorrect in your design. In this case make sense to use an overloaded methods or mapping library

Comment: Have you considered moving the `ApplyProperties` logic into classes A and B?

Comment: Yes, But I cannot do that because by doing so I have to write similar types of codes at two different places. Now the ApplyProperties methos is a generic method in a CommonHelper class @mjwills

Comment: Why not put that similar code in a third class, which A and B can invoke if required?

Answer (score -1):

You can use pattern matching

```
        if (serviceResponse is A newObj) // where A = class name
        {
            //Assign properties of Consumer obj here.
        }
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/pattern-matching