# How can I supply a type in a generic method to use for casting?

Tags: c#, generics

I have these two methods:

```
private int GetInt(string key)
{
    try
    {
        return (int)_data[key];
    } catch (KeyNotFoundException)
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
private int? GetNullableInt(string key)
{
    try
    {
        return (int?)_data[key];
    } catch (KeyNotFoundException)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

But, I would like to create one generic method, to prevent code duplication, along the lines of:

```
private T Get<T>(string key, T type)
{
    try
    {
        return (T)_data[key];
    } catch (KeyNotFoundException)
    {
        return default(T);
    }
}
```

However, I don't seem to get this right. The method compiles, but I have no idea how to call it:

```
Get("myKey", typeof(int));
```

doesn't work.

```
Get("myKey", int);
```

would be my preference, but that seems to be invalid syntax.

Comment: You're close. `private T Get<T>(string key)`, and call it as `Get<int>("key")`

Comment: If `_data` is an `IDictionary<,>` you should really use `TryGetValue`

Comment: @xanatos thanks. With using the generic, this means only one place to change the code :)

Comment: @canton7 sounds like an answer to me!

Comment: It's almost certainly a dup, but it's such an elementary question that I'm having trouble finding anything...

Comment: See: [Generic Methods (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/generic-methods).

Comment: If you go with `T Get<T>(string key) => (T)_data[key]`, then you'll probably (depends on `_data`) have [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39244449/1997232).

Comment: FYI the correct way to make the call the way you defined the method would be `Get("myKey", 1)` as in you have to pass an `int` value, not the type for it to be inferred, but as already mentioned it's better to just state the generic type in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using generic dictionaries and en extension method. i.e. something like:

```
    public static T GetOrDefault<TKey, T>(this IDictionary<TKey, T> self, TKey key)
    {
        if (self.TryGetValue(key, out var value))
        {
            return value;
        }

        return default;
    }

    public static T? GetOrNullable<TKey, T>(this IDictionary<TKey, T> self, TKey key) where T : struct
    {
        if (self.TryGetValue(key, out var value))
        {
            return value;
        }

        return null;
    }
```

And call it like

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, int>();
var valueOrDefault = dict.GetOrDefault("test");
var valueOrNull = dict.GetOrNullable("test");
```

This lets the compiler infer the type arguments.

If you really need non generic dictionaries, or a `Dictionary<string, object>` you also need to consider what will happen if the object is not the type you requested.