# Cast generic class object to non-generic

Tags: c#, casting, type-conversion

I have 2 classes:

```
public class GenericClass<T>
{
   public T Item {get;set;}
}
public class StringClass
{
  public string Item {get;set;}
}
```

now i have a GenericClass object and i need to cast it to StringClass object:

```
var genericObj = new GenericClass<string>();
var stringObj = (StringClass)genericObj; // <---
```

How to cast / convert from generic class to specific one?

Comment: This sounds like a job for AutoMapper.

Answer (score 0):

You can't cast one type to the other because the types are unrelated.

You could, however, define a [conversion operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/user-defined-conversion-operators):

```
public class StringClass
{
    public string Item { get; set; }
    
    public static explicit operator StringClass(GenericClass<string> generic)
        => new StringClass { Item = generic.Item };
}
```

Which would allow this syntax:

```
var genericObj = new GenericClass<string>();
var stringObj = (StringClass)genericObj;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't. You would need common inherited type or implement an interface.

With inheritance:

```
public class GenericClass<T>
{
   public T Item {get;set;}
}
public class StringClass : GenericClass<string>
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if your really need it, you can do this way for examle

```
var stringObj = new  StringClass(genericObj);

public class StringClass
{
    public string Item { get; set; }
    
    public StringClass(GenericClass<string> genericClass)
    {
        Item=genericClass.Item;
    }
 
   public StringClass(){}
}
```

or this is more flexible

```
public interface IGenericClass<T>
{
    public T Item { get; set; }
}
public class GenericClass<T>:IGenericClass<T>
{
    public T Item { get; set; }
}
public class StringClass
{
    public string Item { get; set; }
    
    public StringClass(IGenericClass<string> genericClass)
    {
        Item=genericClass.Item;
    }
   
    public StringClass(){}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39244683/17866351):

```
var genericObj = new GenericClass<string>();
var stringObj = (StringClass)Convert.ChangeType(genericObj, typeof(StringClass));
```

Comment: This results in an `InvalidCastException`, by bypassing the compiler checks that tried to prevent that from happening.

Answer (score -1):

Finally i solved using ICloneable,

Here i have a base class named **GenericClass**, a generic class named **GenericClassT**, and a class named **StringClass**.

Inheritance is:

**GenericClass** <- **GenericClassT** <- **StringClass**

Using ICloneable implementation on GenericClass and GenericClassT, adding a CreateObject and CopyTo methods i reach the final goal:

```
var genericObj = new GenericClass<string>();
var stringObj = (StringClass)genericObj.Clone<StringClass>();
```

class definitions:

```
public class GenericClass: ICloneable
{
    public string Id {get;set;}

    protected virtual ApiRequestResult CreateObject()
    {
        return new GenericClass();
    }
    protected virtual void CopyTo(GenericClass obj)
    {
        obj.Id = Id;
    }
    public virtual object Clone()
    {
        var obj = CreateObject();

        CopyTo(obj);

        return obj;
    }
    public virtual object Clone<T>() where T: GenericClass
    {
        var obj = (GenericClass)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T));

        CopyTo(obj);

        return obj;
    }
}

public class GenericClass<T>: GenericClass
{
    public T Data {get; set;}

    protected override GenericClass CreateObject()
    {
        return new GenericClass<T>();
    }
    protected override void CopyTo(GenericClass obj)
    {
        base.CopyTo(obj);
        ((GenericClass<T>)obj).Data = Data;
    }
}

public class StringClass: GenericClass<string>
{
    
}
```

Comment: Now automapper can take a rest. We don' t need them anymore. You have done the alternative.